# jquery image load strange behaviour

Tags: jquery, html, image

I have a page which has a img holder with the html: -

```
<img src="someimage.jpeg" alt="image" class="show_image"/>
```

Now i m updating the image with jquery using the code...

```
$('.show_image').attr('src', 'anotherimage.jpeg');
```

now when the image gets loaded i want to run some code...

as image scaling and letting the user know image is loaded

i run this code to know the image is loaded...

```
 var inc = 0;
    $('.show_image').load(function() {
        inc++;
        console.log('image loaded '+inc);
    });
```

now on repeatedly updating the img src the above load function is showing a strange

behaviour and is being called the number of times the img src is updated...

take a look at the firebig logs at this page...(use the prev n next buttons above)

pradyut.dyndns.org/original_image.jsp#imgid=202

i think i have to run the code like this

```
if(inc==1) {
  //run code
}
```

Any help

Thanks

Comment: You want the function in the `load` event to fire only once, correct?

Comment: ya (stackoverflow doesn't allow less charachetrs :D )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [jQuery's `.one()` method](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

```
$('.show_image').one('load', function() {
    inc++;
    console.log('image loaded '+inc);
});
```

This removes the handler after the first time it runs.

Comment: nice one...(stackoverflow doesn't allow less charachetrs :D)

Answer (score 0):

Only bind the load event once on the image, not every time that you load a new image.

Alternatively, use the `unbind` method to unbind any previous load event before binding a new one.

Comment: but i want to know the image is loaded or not everytime a new image is being loaded...or i could not understand you.. please some code..

Comment: The event handler *will* be called every time a new image is loaded if you only bind it once. The event handler is not removed when you change the `src` property, it still remains. You have actually used the `bind` method before, just not directly. When the `load` method is used with a function, it actually the same as `.bind('load', func)`. You can use `.unbind('load')` to unbind that specific event, or simply `.unbind()` to unbind all events.